# Cannot pass size_t *arg[] to function requiring array of void pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

My function `f(void *data[])` is supposed to receive an array of generic pointers as an argument, as far as I understand.
Nonetheless, I get a compilation error when I try to do

```
size_t *cnt[8];
... // initialize pointers in cnt
f(cnt);
```

In particular g++ automatically converts the prototype of `f` into `f(void**)`, then it converts `cnt` to `size_t**`, and than it says that it cannot convert `size_t**` to `void**`.

Comment: Why not use a template and actual types instead of `void*`?

Comment: It isn't a g++ thing. It is C++. `f(void *data[])` is the same as `f(void** data)`

Comment: Anyway, it is the expected behviour. But what is your question?

Comment: To see why that conversion isn't allowed, consider what could happen: `void f(void* d[]) { d[0] = new int; } int main() { string * cnt[8] = {0}; f(cnt); *cnt[0] = "Oops"); }`

Answer (score 0):

> g++ automatically converts the prototype of `f` into `f(void**)`

I find that using exact terminology helps understand programming languages better. It may be confusing to think that `f` is *converted* into `f(void**)`. That's not pedantically speaking the case.`f(void *data[])` is simply another way to write `f(void** data)`. This, alternative syntax, is a case of *syntactic sugar*.

Conversion typically means change of one type into another. There is no conversion involved in the declaration of your function.

Also, this syntactic sugar is not specific to the compiler g++. This behaviour is specified in the C++ standard.

> ```
> f(cnt);
> ```
>
> then it converts `cnt` to `size_t**`

This *is* a conversion indeed. It is a special type of conversion called *decaying*. This implicit conversion is also a case syntactic sugar. It is semantically same as writing:

```
f(&cnt[0]);
```

---

> Cannot pass size_t *arg[] to function requiring array of void pointers

This is correct.

Indeed, your function expects a `void**` but you passed the function a `size_t**`. A `size_t**` is not implicitly convertible to `void**`, so your program is ill-formed.

Ways to fix the problem:

1) Use `f(size_t**)` instead.

2) Use an array of `void*` in the first place

3) Copy `size_t *cnt[8]` into another array `void *temp[8]`, and pass that to the function.

4) (not recommended) Cast `cnt` to `void**` and hope that it does what your function expects.

Comment: More like syntactic pepper

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I would have used "syntactic saccharin": tries to be syntactic sugar but causes cancer - if only the analogy wasn't weakened by the lack of evidence that saccharin was associated with cancer in *humans*.

Comment: Heh, yep that'll do

Answer (score -1):

Whereas C allows implicit conversion from any type pointer-to-pointer to `void` pointer-to-pointers, C++ does not allow this. You would need to explicitly cast `cnt` to `void **`.

Comment: Note that any decent C compiler would at least warn if you implicitly convert an arbitrary pointer to `void**`.